# Which firestore rule to show all documents with my uid in flutter?

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I'm building an app which saves the data in cloud firestore.

In firestore a have a collection called projects in which I saved an array with `userIDs`.
In my app, I want to show and edit all projects, with my `userID`.

Can you give me a rule which provides this condition?

I tested some rules which worked in the test environment in firebase but not in my app.
I always have problems with the permissions.

Please ask if you need more information.

My Rule:

```
service cloud.firestore {
   match /databases/{database}/documents {


      match /projects/{projectsId} {
         allow create: if request.auth != null;
         allow read, update, delete, write: if request.auth.uid in        get(/databases/$(database)/documents/projects/$(projectsId)).data.member
         }

      match /user/{userId} {
         allow create, read: if request.auth != null;
        }
  }

 }
```

member is an array in every project.

My Code(Stream):

```
  //get projects stream
  Stream<List<Project>> get projects {
    return projectCollection.snapshots().map(_projectListFromSnapshot);
  }


  
 //Project list from snapshot
  List<Project> _projectListFromSnapshot(QuerySnapshot snapshot) {
    return snapshot.docs.map((doc) {
      return Project(
        name: doc.data()['name'] ?? '',
        subject: doc.data()['subject'] ?? '',
        member: doc.data()['member'] ?? '',
        date: doc.data()['date'].toDate() ?? '',
        projectID: doc.id,
        open: doc.data()['open'] ?? '',
      );
    }).toList();
  }
```

With a `StreamProvider`, I build a `ListView` with every object from the `List<Project>`

Comment: Note that [rules are not filters](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-conditions?authuser=0#rules_are_not_filters).

Answer (score 0):

**1 . This rule for only authentic use is add/edit/update your database,**

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    // Allow only authenticated content owners access
    match /some_collection/{document} {
      allow read, write: if request.auth.uid != null;
      }
    }
  }
```

**2 . This rule for everyone use is add/edit/update your database without needed authentication,**

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write: if true;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: request.resource.data.member doesnt work: "Error: simulator.rules line [6], column [81]. Property resource is undefined on object."

Comment: check again this rule

Answer (score 0):

```
 service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {


    match /projects/{document} {
      allow read, write, delete: if request.auth != null && request.auth.uid in resource.data.member
      }
    
    match /user/{userId} {
      allow create, read: if request.auth != null;
    }
  }
    
}
```

works in the test environment.

In Android Studio (Flutter) i receive an error:

```
════════ Exception caught by provider ══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
The following assertion was thrown:
An exception was throw by _MapStream<QuerySnapshot, List<Project>> listened by

StreamProvider<List<Project>>, but no `catchError` was provided.

Exception:
[cloud_firestore/permission-denied] The caller does not have permission to execute the specified operation.

════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
Reloaded 0 of 643 libraries in 649ms.
W/Firestore( 4590): (22.0.0) [Firestore]: Listen for Query(target=Query(projects order by __name__);limitType=LIMIT_TO_FIRST) failed: Status{code=PERMISSION_DENIED, description=Missing or insufficient permissions., cause=null}

══╡ EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY PROVIDER ╞══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
The following assertion was thrown:
An exception was throw by _MapStream<QuerySnapshot, List<Project>> listened by
StreamProvider<List<Project>>, but no `catchError` was provided.

Exception:
[cloud_firestore/permission-denied] The caller does not have permission to execute the specified
operation.

════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
```